# is it good to use flask api with django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, flask-restful

I and my friend was discussing a project idea and I wanted to do it using DRF with vue.js on the front end.
then he told me that using flask API with DRF will make the performance better.
I really don't remember how and why.
do you agree with him and why?

Comment: Flask with DRF is not very common setup, I'd say...

Comment: Not really. I mean using flask with drf is not very comman at all. I personaly do not see need to wrap one franework into another (drf is allready “wrapper” around Django itself).

Comment: Why would you need both? DRF offers everything that flask does (except for relative simplicity). Also, performance would probably depend more on how you architect things than the framework used. Most time is spent waiting for user input on web anyways. A core part of being able to increase performance is by making the business logic platform/framework-agnostic, so that it is easy to switch between two frameworks if that is a problem. (it probably would not be). Almost all python frameworks could reach a few thousand RPS (on somewhat complex requests), if optimised properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would totally agree with @SUTerliakov and @TheOriginalOdis

It's a very unusual combo and whether or not this is a good idea. But if we see it in terms of performance, it's also difficult to say which combination of web framework and API toolkit would be the "best" without knowing more about the specific requirements of your project. Both Flask and DRF are well-established and widely used tools, so either one could be a good choice depending on your needs.

It's worth considering factors like the size and complexity of your project and the performance requirements.